# Как создать объект, аналогичный Double, но со своими методами?

Tags: c#, классы, типы

Я бы хотел сделать тип температуры, который вел себя как double, но в нем бы просто был еще метод конвертации в другие единицы.
В общем настоящее значение переменной Т считается в кельвинах, и ему можно было бы присваивать значение, но у него к примеру может быть метод ConvertTo(string unit).

```
class Program
{
    Temperature T = 298.15;                                     // В принципе это то же, что и double T = 298.15;

    Console.WriteLine(T + "(K) = " T.ConvertTo("C") + "(C)"); // 298.15(K) = 25(C) 
                                                                // Но у типа Temperature просто есть
                                                                // метод ConvertTo(string unit)

    // Если делать T структурой, у которой есть поле Value, то запись формул будет громоздкой:
    double p;
    p = R * T.Value / Vm;

    // А хотелось бы так:
    p = R * T / Vm;
}
```

Или посоветуйте другие способы для создания типов, у которых есть единица измерения. Я смотрел как на msdn приводят примеры с классами Temperature - и они все неудобные для реального использования в формулах. Мне просто понадобится аналогичные типы делать для давления, объема и т.д - то есть по дефолту надо хранить значение в единицах СИ (К, Па, м3), но и конвертацию тоже надо как-то учесть.

Comment: [implicit operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Comment: это работает к строчке типа `Temperature T = 298.15`, но если Т использовать в выражениях типа `double something = 2.33 * T`, то пишет ошибку - не может применить умножение между double и Temperature

Comment: [Операторы можно переопределять](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Comment: возможно вам пригодится https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311333/A-Csharp-Temperature-Struct

Comment: В принципе если переопределить операторы, то все будет работать как я и хотел, но неужели нет способа как-то полаконичнее скопировать поведение double и добавить туда маленькую надстройку?